# How to modify standalone.xml in JBOSS so that it is visible from outside?

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x, ubuntu-14.04

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 image and i have installed JBOSS. I have a static ip and i want to access the admin console of JBOSS from another pc. I have changed standalone.xml like this:

```
    <interface name="management">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:128.x.x.x}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="public">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:128.x.x.x}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="unsecure">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure:128.x.x.x}"/>
    </interface>
```

When i start JBOSS everything seems ok, but when i try to access JBOSS from my computer (http://128.x.x.x:9990/console) i get that the website is not available. I can ping 128.199.35.98, which the ip of the ubuntu server, where JBOSS is installed.

Comment: so is port 9990 the HTTP port in the socket bindings then? And is the HTTP traffic allowed by whatever security measures you have installed? Perhaps you need to setup port forwarding in your router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When changing the address and or port the server listens on you need to ensure the firewall allows that port to be accessed.

Something like

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 9990 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: I have been trying a lot of things and in the end i turned off the firewall. Now, i can turn it on again. Thanks